# Why can't controls in Templates be referenced via their parent?

Tags: asp.net

I've been wondering to why you have to use `FindControl` to reference the checkbox in the `Login1`'s LayoutTemplate. Example:

```
var login1CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)Login1.FindControl("CheckBox1");
```

I would expect to be able to do something along the lines of:

```
var login1CheckBox1 = Login1.LayoutTemplate.CheckBox1;
```

In the case of the `Repeater` below, it is obvious, because there can be n number of CheckBoxes.
But for the `Login` control, it doesn't seem to make sense.  Why wouldn't this be implemented differently?

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Does anyone have any light to shine on this?

Answer (score 0):

A control added to a page via markup is defined in the designer partial class, generally, at design time.

A control added to a template is generally instantiated programmatically within the control's collection of controls.

Since the control added to the template does not exist at compile-time in the definition of that control, it would be rather impossible to achieve the syntax you're aiming for.

When creating a page in markup, we're using the IDE's facilities to generate a partial class.  When defining a template in markup, we're simply setting the value of the [ITemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.aspx) for that control.